# What does "invoked" mean in the standard when referring to destructor?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, destructor

Does *invoked* mean that a destructor has been called and completed/returned, or simply that it has been called? I thought the latter until I saw this sentence in the 12.4 Destructors section (multiple drafts have this):

> Once a destructor is invoked for an object, the object no longer exists

If *invoked* means just that the call had started, that would imply that `this` was invalid in the body of the destructor.

If *invoked* means called and completed, that would imply that an object still "*exists*" while its destructor is running and could be accessed from perhaps another thread (which is what had me looking at the standard in the first place). Other answers claim this isn't the case, but don't back it up with sources so I'm inclined to think they are wrong.

Comment: `that would imply that an object still "exists" while its destructor is running and could be accessed from perhaps another thread` .. that's one of the points of a dtor .. resource clean up .. and a `std::mutex`, to ensure you don't access a disposed object ..

Answer (score 6):

This is simple. First, one interpretation of *this particular statement* yields a contradiction, and another interpretation doesn't. Choose. Secondly, the standard assumes a certain amount of common sense on the part of the reader. For example, not assuming that a term is context-independent.

Comment: Where does the standard say it assumes the reader has common sense?

Comment: @RyanHaining People without common sense do C, so we're safe

Comment: @RyanHaining: By reference, it's in one of the ISO procedural standards. And in _slightly_ different words. IIRC, "unless defined otherwise, words have their normal English meaning". That's why C++ explicitly defines "expression", you can't apply common sense to derive the C++ meaning.

Comment: @MSalters my "common-sense" translation of "invoke" would be that something called the function, but not that it is necessarily finished yet, I guess I'm wrong. in retrospect I should have asked this question more specifically about whether you can have another member function running at the same time as the destructor.